# Improperly handled exit code of subshell in a function

Tags: bash, shell-script

Bash 5.2.15 here.

Running the following script, I'm expecting the echo to not be run.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e  

function func() {
  (
    exit 1 
  )

   echo 'should not be run because of set -e'
}

func || true
```

It's actually run, which seems as a bug to me.

It's (correctly) not run if I remove the `|| true` at the function call's site.

My interpretation is that the "error swallowing" `|| true` is applied at the wrong part of the code: it is as if I had written it right  on the same line as the subshell's closing parenthesis (but I did not).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set) [**emphasis** mine]:

> `-e`
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists of Commands), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status. **The shell does not exit if the command that fails is […] part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`,** […]. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while `-e` was being ignored, the shell does not exit. […]

> […]

> **If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where `-e` is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the `-e` setting, even if `-e` is set and a command returns a failure status.** […]

This means that in your `func || true` `-e` is being ignored before `||` and *it's being ignored in the entire function.*

Comment: Seems like a very bad case of premature optimization (short circuiting). I know that bash is wonky at places, but having the way a function is called impact the way the function behaves on its own is crazy :o prevents reliable testing etc. Thanks for the info, though!